# Looping over JSON hash/dictionary

Tags: jsrender

There was an [issue opened a few years ago on JsRender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/issues/40) to allow looping over objects and not just arrays. One of the examples given that helped to reopen the issue was [this](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/issues/40#issuecomment-3641893):

```
{
    joe:{
        name:  'Joe',
        status: 'out'},
    jane:{
        name: 'Jane',
        status:'in'},
    jill:{
        name:'Jill',
        status:'away'}
}
```

Eventually, the feature was implemented but none of the examples I've found address this particular problem, it's always some subset of the data, [as in the examples given at the end of the issue thread](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/blob/master/demos/scenarios/03_iterating-through-fields-scenario.html), usually looking something like this from the docs for [`for`](http://www.jsviews.com/#fortag):

```
[
  {
    "name": "Pete",
    "address": {
      "city": "Seattle"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Heidi",
    "address": {
      "city": "Sidney"
    }
  }
]
```

**How can I use [`for`](http://www.jsviews.com/#fortag) or [`props`](http://www.jsviews.com/#propstag) to iterate over a *dictionary*** like the one further above? (**not** an array of objects) Whatever I try I receive the error:

> …expected expression, got ':'

Or whatever fits the permutation I try:

```
{{for :data}}
{{for :#data}}
{{for :}}
```

etc. It's pretty normal (in my experience) to encounter dictionaries with an index like this in a JSON file so I'm surprised not to find any examples for it.

I'm not using JsViews, just JsRender v0.9.87.

Answer (score 0):

There are several examples of `{{props}}` here:

http://www.jsviews.com/#propstag

In the examples you have `{{props address}}` - but if you want to iterate over the top-level object, you can use either `{{props #data}}` or `{{props}}` (since the object you want to iterate over is the current data context...).

The syntax `{{for :#data}}` is incorrect (not sure where that came from). 
As the error message says, there should not be a colon there. It would be `{{for #data}}` or `{{for}}` if you want to iterate over current data.

(BTW there is also a {{jsonview}} tag which can also be used with JsRender, not only with JsViews. http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/tag-controls/jsonview. Not sure if it is relevant to your scenarios though. It is actually a sample showing `{{props}}` running on the current data, though with data-binding. See also http://www.jsviews.com/#jsvpropstag@jsonview)

Here is a [new sample](https://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/f70pnkwa/) (jsfiddle) which takes the http://www.jsviews.com/#samples/editable/tags sample and replaces the movies array by a movies hash. You can see use of {{props}} to iterate over the top-level dictionary. I'll add the sample to jsviews.com later...